# Redirect DNS requests using a router and iptables

Tags: networking, router, dns, iptables

I have a cable-modem-router from my ISP (Technicolor TC7210Z), and a bunch of wired and wireless devices connected.  I want to change the DNS configuration for all devices, but I cannot change it on the cable modem, nor can I change it on some of the connected devices.  Right now it looks like this:

[image: current network setup with no control over DNS servers]

As well as not being able to set the DNS on the ISP-supplied cable-modem-router, I believe the DNS IPs are hardcoded on the device in question (Wireless device X) and not pulled from DHCP, and so using `iptables` and mapping the requested DNS IPs to my preferred DNS IPs would be necessary.  To this end, I am considering purchasing another router (Linksys WRT54GL), flashing with DD-WRT (if necessary), and placing it between the devices and the router-modem and configuring `iptables`, like so:

[image: proposed setup with additional router allowing DNS redirects using iptables]

I don't want to drop money on new hardware without being pretty confident that this will work, so I have these questions:

1. will this have the desired effect of changing the DNS data on Wireless Device X?
2. assuming there are no special requirements from DNS on any of the other connected devices, will this have any side effects?  Will communications between devices behind the new router (the devices inside my network) be affected?
3. is it common to use DNS to perform tasks other than domain name lookups?

Comment: Can you disable dhcp on your ISP supplied router?  Then you can have some other device on your network supply the necessary settings via dhcp.  But that relies on being able to turn dhcp off on the isp router.  And if that is feasible some other tricks can come into play.  Otherwise, your plan of the DD-WRT is probably the way to go.

Comment: I didn't think of using another device as the DHCP provider.  The ISP-supplied router has options for disabling DHCP on the LAN (although does not supply any interface for changing the DNS servers even when DHCP is switched off).  In this case however I think it won't work.  The Wireless device has hardcoded DNS IPs (ignoring ones from DHCP), so whilst this would work for other devices, that device would still use its hardcoded DNS IPs.

Comment: The trick depends upon well you know your networking.  For the hardcoded dns addresses, create a separate subnet on your network which includes those special dns addresses.  Create a special host which listens on those addresses.  Run something llike dnsmasq on that host to handle the dns resolution.  It can also be your main dns and dhcp server.  The drawback is that you won't be able to get to those addresses externally, as they have been rerouted internally.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm learning a lot.  One of the devices is an aways-on RasberryPI connected via ethernet, and the device with the hardcoded DNS is a wireless device.  Could I create the subnet (+dnsmasq) on the RPi and expose it to the LAN, or do I need an additional router to create the subnet? If using a RPi is conceptually correct, would there be performance implications?  Second question: assuming I have the subnet set up, would additional configuration be required to allow devices to communicate across subnets, or am I better off having everything on the same subnet?

Comment: All good questions.  And various combinations of concepts like default gateway, bridging, vlans, secondary ip addresses, routing, ... come into play.  The raspberry pi, being linux based, may be able to perform all those things for you from a command line perspective.   ip link, ip neigh, ip addr, ip route, ... are some of the commands which would be of value.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to lay the whole thing out for you.

Comment: You've been more than helpful and given me a lot to go on. Thanks very much for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Purchasing a wireless router with configuration under your control is the easiest way to do this.  Based on your described scenario, you *have* to put something between the non-controllable ISP router and your other devices to at least intercept DHCP request packets and change the response behavior (for what DNS servers to use).  You wouldn't even need to worry about DD-WRT as pretty much *any* wireless router you can buy at your local Big Box store will let you specify the DNS servers handed out by the DHCP function built-in to that device, as well as a bunch of other features (firewalls, port forwarding, blacklists, whitelists, etc.)  This can be had really cheaply, for as little as $25 for a basic model.

And you can of course spend more $$ to get a much better wireless upgrade, e.g., to 802.11ac standard (as of this writing).

The only thing you still won't have control over is any funny business going on inside of your ISPs infrastructure upstream from your cable modem, e.g., a lot of ISPs these days intercept **all** DNS queries -- regardless of where they are destined -- and redirect to their own servers.  Caveat Emptor.  If that's going on, things get deeply interesting to get around that.

Comment: I didn't even consider that the ISP might route DNS requests like that.  Fortunately they are not in my case.  Thanks for a great answer.   As I said in the comment above, it will not be enough to change the DNS provided by DHCP as the devices have hardcoded DNS IPs and completely ignore the DHCP-provided DNS IPs.  The only way I think is to reroute DNS request traffic destination IP (or block it in case the device starts hitting the correct DNS IPs).  I think I'll leave 802.11ac for now - it is significantly more expensive and none of my devices support it at the moment.